# Como recorrer un arreglo en java

Tags: java, array, netbeans, bucles, arraylist

Hola necesito recorrer un arreglo y validar cada posición
lo que necesito es que mediante el recorrido se vaya comparando si es igual a un carácter dado sino es igual sumar el contador de 40 en 40
Ejemplo

```
String numeroaigualar = "09";

String horas[] = {"07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13"};
```

al recorrer se encuentra con el 07 no es igual entonces sumar 40, luego sigue el 08, sumar 40 mas, luego el 09 entonces este si es igual al numeroaigualar parar el bucle y imprimir la suma total del recorrigo que en este caso solo dio dos saltos seria 40 + 40 = 80.

Espero me puedan ayudar :(

hasta ahora tengo esto

```
int i = 0;
              
   while (i < horas.length) {

  i++;

 }
```

Me imprime todo el arreglo si le pongo un if que iguale me da un bucle infinito

Comment: Entiendo que estás aprendiendo recién. ¿Por qué usas un ciclo `while` en lugar de un ciclo `for`? ¿Aún no llegan a ese tema en tu curso o se te pidió usar `while` en particular? Mencionas que te imprime todo el arreglo y algo de un `if`, ¿podrías compartir eso también?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplemente, encuentra el valor dentro del array `horas[]` cuando coincide con `numeroaigualar`  recuerda que debes usar `.equals()` en este caso, ya que es una cadena, y termina el bucle con `break`. En caso de que el valor dentro del array `horas[]` coincida con `numeroaigualarno', suma 40 a una variable` contador` .

```
  int contador = 0;
  String numeroaigualar = "09";
  String horas[] = {"07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13"};
  int i = 0;
  while (i < horas.length) {
      if(numeroaigualar.equals(horas[i])){
         System.out.println("valor en arreglo es igual a : " + horas[i] + " , termina...");
         break; //Termina
      }else{
          //Si es diferente a numeroaigualar, continua contando.
          contador = contador + 40;
      }
      i++;
  }
  System.out.println("valor contador: " + contador);
```

Salida:

```
valor en arreglo es igual a : 09 , termina...
valor contador: 80
```

Comment: si gracias @Jorgesys me sirvió